# How to insert Data to MS access using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

I created a database in ms access, in the database I have a table with two columns, fist column is `Name` with `Text` data type, and the other column is `Date` with `Date/time` data type. and I want to insert values in the table, but it give this error for the month calendar

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

```
string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO register (`Name`,`Date`) values (?,?)";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\DB.accdb"))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", this.textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", this.monthCalendar1.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Lose the ` backticks, use `[date]` to escape reserved words in Access

Comment: Use the form of parameter addition that lets you specify the data type.

Comment: Can we stop using AddWithValue? http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @AlexK. Actually, grave accent (`) works to escape them as well.

Comment: Oh learnt something new, I assumed this was a MySQL mashup.

Comment: @AlexK. At least they work on OleDb Jet 4.0 provider. I don't have any knowledge for the other versions.

Answer (score 4):

> and the other column is Date with Date/time data type

The problem is you try to insert this column a string which is `this.monthCalendar1.Text`. You need to pass the `DateTime` *directly* to it.

We don't know what this `monthCalendar1` control exactly but it should have some `SelectedDate` property or something. If does not have, just parse this string to `DateTime` with `DateTime.Parse` or something.

Do not use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overloads to specify your [parameter type](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320435) and it's size.

Answer (score -1):

remove this from AddwithValue paranthesis

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `this` keyword here. It is just to explicitly say that you are using the instance objects of current calss